# How do I use MultiRes modifier here?

Tags: mesh, texturing, sculpting, texture-painting

Figured out I had to use MultiRes modifier in order to use alpha brushes with image as textures, and that has worked for two other files. However, with this one it just isn't working. Did I use the wrong image? The MultiRes modifier has not been applied yet.

[image: before]

[image: after]

Comment: I have realized it was at 1.0 strength but I am now facing other problems. They are in another question.

Comment: I FIGURED IT ALL OUT NEVERMIND LOVE THIS WEBSITE